# Perl web API using Data::Dumper

Tags: web-services, perl, mod-perl, data-dumper

We've developed an open web API using Apache and mod_perl, where you can pass text created by Data::Dumper to make requests.

Our data generally looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'OurField' => 'OurValue'
};
```

Currently, I noticed we're using an `eval` to get the data back into a Perl hash server side:

```
my $VAR1;
eval $our_dumper_string;
#$VAR1 is now filled with hash value
```

The problem with this, is it is a major security issue.  You can pass malicious perl code in there and it will run server side...

It there a better way to safely take a Data::Dumper string and turn it into a hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use JSON::XS and use JSON rather than Data::Dumper format. That is much more compatible with other web APIs

Comment: We also support XML, YAML, and JSON.  This is just a 4th format currently used by our perl devs.  We would like to continue to support it, b/c it is currently in use...

Comment: OK, I was being a touch abrupt, and I guessed that could be an issue. However, there are other issues. First, you can't really control what core modules do, so they could change, except for compatibility with eval. Probably your best bet is the CPAN Safe module, to box off the eval so it do some of the code things. That would leave Data::Dumper intact, but address the security issue.

Comment: We are going to try using Safe, I think it looks like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is simple and predictable you can even try to write a simple "parser" to read back the values in a data stricture

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = { 'key1' => 'value' };

my $dumper = Dumper($data);

print $dumper;

my $data_2;

while( $dumper =~ /(.+)$/mg) {
    if ( $1 =~ m/'(.*)' => '(.*)'/ ) {
        $data_2->{$1} = $2;
    }
}

print Dumper( $data_2 );
```

(this is just an example and wont work with integers or nested data structures)